# Whats is the sum of series for each $0\le x\le 3$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $\psi(x)=\begin{cases}0:& 0<x<1\\ 1:& 1<x<3 \end{cases}$

a) Compute the first 4 terms of its Fourier cosine series explicitly.

b) For each $x (0\le x\le 3)$, whats is the sum of this series?

a) We have that $\phi(x)=\begin{cases}0:& 0<x<1\\ \frac{2}{3}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{-2\sin(m\pi/3)}{m\pi}\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{3}):& 1<x<3 \end{cases}$

Thus the fisrt four terms are $\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{\pi}\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})\cos(\frac{\pi x}{3})-\frac{1}{\pi}\sin(\frac{2\pi}{3})\cos(\frac{2\pi x}{3})-\frac{1}{2\pi}\sin(\frac{4\pi}{3})\cos(\frac{4\pi x}{3})$

b)  Note that by the interval definition of $x$ we cannot consider $0$ nor $3$ thus in $(0,1),\phi=0$. And now I wonder how will I calculate the sum of the series in $(1,3)?$

I don't think brute force is a solution

Can somebody help me?

---

**edit:** I had a typo in the definition of Fourier series, it's 2/3 instead of 4/3. Sorry.

**edit 2:** According to H.Gutsche's comment, the sum of the series in the interval $0\le x\le 3$ is $\phi(x)=\begin{cases}1/2:& 0\\0:& 0<x<1\\1/2:& 1\\ 1:& 1<x<3\\1/2:& 3 \end{cases}$ by Dirichlet Theorem. I don't know what exactly states that Theorem nor how was applied to get $\phi$. I found this
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series which mention Dirichlet but it says something about an integral and I don't see how that would help.

Please shed some light here, I'm not understanding.

Comment: Isn't the actual question precisely what happens with the series at 0, 1, and 3? If the given series is the Fourier series it should converge to the values of the given function outside of its discontinuities. At the discontinuities there is something happening involving the left and the right limits at these points.

Comment: @H.Gutsche Nop, the actual question (as is stated in the text) is as I wrote b)

Comment: b) says 0, 1 and 3 are values to be considered. outside of this the Fourier series should precisely do what it is supposed to do i.e. give $0$ for $0<x<1$, and $1$ for $1<x<3$. Then Dirichlet tells me that that the value for $0,1$, and $3$ is $1/2$

Comment: @H.Gutsche Dirichlet? What proposition/result by Dirichlet are you talking about to say that the value for $0,1$ and $3$ is $1/2$?

Comment: DIrichlet's theorem (as the chosen name suggests) about Fourier series for functions that fulfill the Dirichlet conditions. There are a number of Dirichlet's theorems around but that's one of the fundamental theorems about the convergence of Fourier series. The thing is even better it is Cesaro summable. For the fun of it you also have Parseval's equation and Bessel's equation.

Comment: @H.Gutsche Are you referring to Pointwise-convergence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series ? If yes, how will I compute the integral?

Comment: @H.Gutsche I am newbie in this, please be patient:)

Comment: @ Al t. Which integral? Where did you get the result under a) from? For the infinite sum under a) to make sens it has to converge for each of the x values (i.e. pointwise). I still don't know what you want to calculate? If it is the Fourier series of the given function(periodically extended) then except for the 3 specific points the value is given by the original function (if it fulfills some conditions, e.g. the Dirichlet conditions.) The only thing to calculate are the Fourier coefficients for the function which you already show under the solution.

Comment: @H.Gutsche The results under a), I did it myself.

Comment: @H.Gutsche The integral that I saw on wikipedia in Pointwise-convergense section

Comment: @H.Gutsche No, I don't want to calculate the Fourier series, I already did it, what I want, or better saying, what the exercise wants is to know the sum of the series in $0\le x\le 3$

Comment: Do you know what Fourier series do? The sum is the given function plus the 3 special values.You original function is not even defined in these points (but has left and right limits, so we can artificially define it in these points with one of those respective limits). So we come back to my original statement that the only interesting points are 0,1, and 3. If you want to see that numerically just use these values in your series and see if reduces to something simple. Quite often one uses Fourier developments to get some surprising series for well known values (the value of the original)

Comment: @H.Gutsche Oh ok, I think I'm understanding. So the sum of the series in $0\le x\le3$ is $\phi(x)+\phi(0)+\phi(1)+\phi(3)?$

Comment: Not quite. It should be $\phi(x)=\begin{cases}1/2, 0\\0, 0<x<1\\1/2, 1\\ 1, 1<x<3\\1/2, 3 \end{cases}$

Comment: @H.Gutsche Ok and the 1/2 came from  $(1/2)[lim_{y\to x^+}\phi(y)+lim_{y\to x^-}\phi(y)]?$

Comment: @Alt. to your last question. Yes, 1/2 comes from there.

Comment: And a side note. I think part a of the question is asking you calculate the coefficient of Fourier series within entire $x\in(0,4)$ domain, but not $x\in(0,1)$ and $x\in(1,3)$ respectively

Comment: @MoonKnight Would you mind to explain the use of $(1/2)[lim_{y\to x^+}\phi(y)+lim_{y\to x^-}\phi(y)]?$ I suspected that the origin of this  $\phi(x)=\begin{cases}1/2, 0\\0, 0<x<1\\1/2, 1\\ 1, 1<x<3\\1/2, 3 \end{cases}$ was $(1/2)[lim_{y\to x^+}\phi(y)+lim_{y\to x^-}\phi(y)]$ because of the $(1/2)$, but I'm not sure how was used. This is my attempt: For $x=0, \lim_{y\to x^-}$ does not exist right? And $\lim_{y\to x^+}=1/2[0]=0$ am I correct?

Comment: @Alt. Again it goes back your understanding of part a.Part a is talking about a Fourier series within $x\in(0,4)$. so this series has a period of 4.  So $\phi(x=0)=\phi(x=4)$. And thus $\phi(x=0) = 0.5[\lim_{x->0^+}\phi(x) + \lim_{x->0^-}\phi(x)] = 0.5[\lim_{x->0^+}\phi(x) + \lim_{x->4^-}\phi(x)] = 0.5$

Comment: @MoonKnight What makes you think part a) is asking me to calculate the coefficient of Fouriers series within $x\in(0,4)$ domain ? I don't understand you 

Comment: @MoonKnight The function $\phi(x)$ is not even defined in $(3,4)$.

Comment: @Alt. Sorry, just replace 4 with 3 in my answer. My reasons to think part a is asking for the entire domain are that 1) you can calculate it even though it is not continuous (2) part b can only have an answer for $\phi(0)$, $\phi(1)$ and $\phi(3)$ if it is one series, but not 2 series separately in 2 domains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, definitely, there has been some confusion around.
Let me try to put some order. I will deal the case "enginering-wise", although rigorously enough.

*1) Periodicity*

If you are using (asked to use) the Fourier **series**, that implicitely means that
you are considering your function $\phi(x)$ **periodic**, and that the definition you are reporting
is describing just one period of it (as it is normal practice).
Explicitly, it shall be written as 
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\varphi (x) = \varphi (x\bmod 3) = \left\{ {\matrix{
   {\,0} \hfill & {\left| {\;0 < x < 1\,} \right.} \hfill  \cr 
   {\,1} \hfill & {\left| {\,1 < x < 3} \right.} \hfill  \cr 
 } } \right.
}$$

So your function looks like in the following sketch

[image: Fourier_Sq_Pulse_1]

and it is a [square pulse wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_wave),
of period $T=3$, and with duty-cycle $2/3$.

*2) Points of non-definition / discontinuity*

The fact that $\phi(x)$ is mathematically undefined at $x=0,1$, but has there finite
left and right limits, is somehow irrelevant to the Fourier series, which being continuous will
(intuitively speaking) provide and "fill the gaps".
It is in fact well known that the Fourier series at the discontinuity points (if "finitely many") takes 
on the average value between the left and right limit: that is the [Dirichlet Theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Dirichlet_theorem)
already mentioned. Have a look at the reference for a rigorous definition.
Thus in our case the Fourier series (the complete one, with infinite terms) will converge at $1/2$ for $x=0$ and $x=1$.
(the first four terms, for $x=0$ return $\phi(x)=0.5288..$).

*3) The Series*

$\phi(x)$, when periodically continued, is symmetric (even) around $x=1/2$, as well around $x=-1$.
So you can express it in terms of only cosines (the even components) of $x-1/2$, or $x+1$.

Thus your expression shall be corrected as:
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & \varphi (x) = {2 \over 3} - \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} {{2 \over {k\pi }}\sin \left( {{{k\pi } \over 3}} \right)\cos \left( {{{2k\pi } \over 3}\left( {x - {1 \over 2}} \right)} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {2 \over 3} + \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} {{2 \over {k\pi }}\sin \left( {{{2k\pi } \over 3}} \right)\cos \left( {{{2k\pi } \over 3}\left( {x + 1} \right)} \right)}  \cr} 
}$$
The following sketch shows the sum up to the eleventh term.

[image: Fourier_Sq_Pulse_2]

*4) the Sum*

Coming to your question b), it is a known property of sinusoidal signals that, if you divide the period
into $2 \le n$ equal parts and take $n$ samples of the signal (at the beginning or at the end of each interval),
the samples' average will be equal to the continuous mean of the signal: thus $0$, unless the frequency is null.
In mathematical terms:
$$
\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \;n - 1} {\cos \left( {\alpha  + 2\pi {k \over n}} \right)}  = 0\quad \left| {\;2 \le n} \right.
$$
which is easy to demonstrate by converting into $e^{ix}$.

Now, if you keep the  division of the base period into $n$ parts, and increase the frequency by multiples of
the fundamental one, and sum the samples, you get
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \;n - 1} {\cos \left( {\alpha  + 2\pi m{k \over n}} \right)}  = \left\{ {\matrix{
   0 & {n\rlap{--} \backslash m}  \cr 
   {n\cos \alpha } & {n\backslash m}  \cr 
 } } \right.
}$$
which is the [Frequency Aliasing effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing),  famous in
the western movies for the [wagon wheel effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon-wheel_effect).

In our case, we are dividing the period by $3$ and taking three samples at $x=1,2,3$.
That would be the same if we take them at  $(2,3,4)$ or at $(1/2,3/2,5/2)$, ..., so we can 
forget about the shift of  $-1/2$ or $+1$ attached to $x$ in the formula above.
And for what told above we shall just consider the frequencies multiple of $3$.
But because the amplitudes (for $0<k$) contain the factor $\sin(k \pi /3)$, they are all null.

Therefore the sum of the series for $x=1,2,3$ (same as for $(0,1,2)$ or $(1/2,3/2,5/2)$, ...),
*independently of how many terms* of it you consider, will always be $3 \times mean$, i.e.
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
3 \cdot 2/3 = 2
}$$
and since it is valid for whichever number of terms, thus also for the complete series, then it is as well equal to
$ 1/2+1+1/2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Glad to help and clear-up a "simple" matter that went messed, and thanks for the bounty. Best wishes for your study on the fascinating world of Fourier coefficients (by the way,  just for curiosity, are you a student ? in engineering or maths ?)

Comment: :) yes of course I'm a student, mathematic student. Althoug I've taken courses that have nothing to do with mathematics for instance philosophy courses at first it was really hard becuase I didn't understand anything, but then things become clearer by the pass of the time..

Comment: @Alt.: well, then *ad majora!*

Answer (score 0):

From MoonKnight comments we can deduce the following

$\phi(x=0) = 0.5[\lim_{x->0^+}\phi(x) + \lim_{x->0^-}\phi(x)] = 0.5[\lim_{x->0^+}\phi(x) + \lim_{x->3^-}\phi(x)] = 0.5[0+1]=.5$

$\phi(x=1) = 0.5[\lim_{x->1^+}\phi(x) + \lim_{x->1^-}\phi(x)] = 0.5[1+0] = 0.5$

$\phi(x=3) = 0.5[\lim_{x->3^+}\phi(x) + \lim_{x->3^-}\phi(x)] = 0.5[\lim_{x->0^+}\phi(x) + \lim_{x->3^-}\phi(x)] = 0.5[0+1]=.5$

Hence

$\phi(x)=\begin{cases}1/2, 0\\0, 0<x<1\\1/2, 1\\ 1, 1<x<3\\1/2, 3 \end{cases}$